# Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() Observer.php on line 8

Tags: event-observer, error

I am new to Magento so any help would be appreciated.
Whenever I click **Catalog > Manage Products** I get the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in
>   /home/designac/public_html/app/code/local/Dac/MultiSku/Model/Observer.php
>   on line 8

The code on line 8 in **Observer.php** is:

```
   $block->getColumn('sku')->setData('filter_condition_callback', array(
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is coming from a third-party extension that has something to do with SKU. You can uninstall or disable the extension `Dac_MultiSku`, if you no longer need it. You can also add this before line 8 `if (!$block->getColumn('sku')) return;` to bypass the observer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to

```
if($block->getColumn('sku')) {
  $block->getColumn('sku')->setData('filter_condition_callback', array('you_callback....'));
}
```